# Entity Framework QueryFilter not applied to related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have set up QueryFilters on all my tables to ignore any entity where `DeletedDate != null`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbEntity>().HasQueryFilter(c => c.DeletedDate == null);
```

This works great for all entities accessed directly through the context.

The below code will return `null` given that the tag has `DeletedDate` set to a non null value.

```
var tagWillBeNull = _context.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == deletedUserTagId);
```

However. In the below code the deleted tag will be returned (given that it is related to the user).

```
var tagWillBeReturned = _context.Users
                                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id)
                                .Tags.Where(t => t.Id == deletedUserTagId);
```

Is there any way to apply query filters to these related entities as well?

I don't want to have to remember to write `.Where(e => e.DeletedDate == null)` on all related entity queries.

**EDIT #1**: this test fails on the last assert:

```
public void SoftDeletedTagNotReturnedForUser()
{
    // setup
    List<User> generatedUsers = SetupDatabaseUsersContent();

    // act
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault();

    var deletedUserTag = user.Tags.FirstOrDefault();

    _context.Tags.Remove(deletedUserTag);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    _context.ChangeTracker.Clear() // added this from comment. Removes problem.

    var tagWillBeNull = _context.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == deletedUserTag.Id);
    var allTagsForUserShouldNotHaveSoftDeleted = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id).Tags.ToList();
    
    // assert
    Assert.Null(tagWillBeNull); // this is OK

    foreach(var tag in allTagsForUserShouldNotHaveSoftDeleted)
        Assert.Null(tag.DeletedDate); // this fails
}
```

**EDIT #2:** This did not work.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    PerformPreSaveProcessing();
    var result = base.SaveChanges();

    this.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you deleted these entities in the same DbContext instance?

Comment: Yes. I have a unittest where I do the above on the same context as it is deleted on. The below code is executed after a `SaveChanges()` and returns the deleted entity.
`var allTagsForUserWithSoftDeleted = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id).Tags.ToList();`. I can debug the code and see that the tag has `DeletedDate` set to a non  null value.

Comment: Add `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` before executing test.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that fixed it. So I have to do this in my code after I do a delete? Why is this not handled automatically? Can i override `SaveChanges()` and do this there for all or will that cause side effects?

Comment: EF Core fixup entities which are already loaded, so they appear in collections. And yes you can clear ChangeTracker after the save if you do not expect performance impact.

Comment: Also note that after clearing ChangeTracker, entities which are stored in some variables in business logic become detached.

Comment: Check Edit2. I thought that would work, but test fails if I remove the Clear() from the unit test.